# Loading image in WebView

Tags: android, html, xml, webview

i have this html tag in my XML file

```
<text><![CDATA[<p><div style="text-align:justify">A certain compound has the molecular formula <img width="40" height="17" align="bottom" alt="mc001-2.jpg" src="@@PLUGINFILE@@/mc001-2.jpg" border="0"> If 10.0 g of the compound contains 5.62 g of X, the atomic mass of X is</div></p>]]></text>
```

and src attribute contain file name which if in another file tag in my XML file which is given below..

```
<file name="mc001-2.jpg" encoding="base64"> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAAEAIwAUAAD//gAfTEVBRCBUZWNobm9sb2dpZXMgSW5jLiBWMS4wMQD/2wCE
AAICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAwMDAwMDAwMDBA UEAwQFBAMDBAYEBQUFBgYGAwQG
BwYGBwUGBgUBAgICAgICAgICAgUDAwMFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQ UFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUF
BQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBf/EAaIAAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKCwEAAwEBA QEB
AQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoLEAACAQMDAgQDBQUEBAAAAX 0BAgMABBEFEiExQQYTUWEHInEU
MoGRoQgjQrHBFVLR8CQzYnKCCQoWFxgZGiUmJygpKjQ1Njc4OT pDREVGR0hJSlNUVVZXWFlaY2Rl
ZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqK mqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK
0tPU1dbX2Nna4eLj5OXm5+jp6vHy8/T19vf4+foRAAIBAgQEAwQHBQQEAAECdwABAgMRBAUhMQYS
QVEHYXETIjKBCBRCkaGxwQkjM1LwFWJy0QoWJDThJfEXGBkaJi coKSo1Njc4OTpDREVGR0hJSlNU
VVZXWFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoKDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5 iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5
usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uLj5OXm5+jp6vLz9PX29/j5+v/AABEIABAACwMBEQACEQEDEQH/
2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AP2M8S/Gm08Ba5f+HfG2g39nqWo3Gz4YQ6Jv1hvig7ou3SdMBSIQa1E+8 z2M
zKiWym9E7W8V09pNH2lem6VCnz4yDlzUbqP7vmfLXU3p9XjHlV eo0nh6l4zjy1MPOvcoxpTVSrNU
8I1H987tQnyrmpTjFOXtJSv9XhFSeIi1GnerGpTh6x4fn1u60X TbnxHp1lpGuT2sc2p6Xp2oPqtn
p1y/zG3jvHhhNzsBCmTy0DMGIGME7VIwhPkp1OdRSXNZpOVlzOKeqj zX5ea0uW3Mk7pYwlKScnTc
LuXLFtcyjzPk5+VuKnycvOoylFTuoylFKT801v4LeHvF+ra9rf ji7vPEmp3gW18KXCltKf4cadE8
M8B8NvA5ew1H7TBFdy6srfaJZIoVysMMUKYU4zoU1KjVdPFc7m 68bc+jkqcIqSlFUYwk4TotSp1+
ao66qRnyR2qTVVxp1KalhoxS9i78km4pTqVGmnKo5X9nNOMsPD lVDkqe0q1fTdBstS03RtNsNY1h
9f1OytIra81uWyt9On1SWMbftMtvb/uYpXADOIwqFixVEUhF3qzjUm5xpKne14xvyp2XNyqTlJR5
ruMXKTjG0XKTXM8KUHSh7N1HNRbs5W5uW75VJpJSko2UpKMVJp y5Y35V/9k=
</file>
```

i got the text OR say String after parsing the xml file in between CDATA type node but when i load it in WebView it makes a box for

```
<img width="40" height="17" align="bottom" alt="mc001-2.jpg" src="@@PLUGINFILE@@/mc001-2.jpg" border="0">
```

my problem is how to load above image tag in webView with its src attribute?????????
also i am little bit confused with path given in src attribute.

screenshots are like this
      [image]

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: where are you storing the images? are they on a server or are they bundled with your apk?

Comment: @dymmeh thanks for instant reply actually images are not at server i need convert the base code of images given in file tag in my XML file and show in the empty box. as shown in screenshot. see the <img> tag under <text> tag. its source attribute contain the same file name that given in file tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a Base64 Coded string that represents an image.

For loading such images in WebView, checkout this post.

[Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAD" />
```

Comment: thanks for reply i want to load in WebView. my code  for loding the string is  **webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, employees.get(i).toString(),  "text/html","UTF-8", null);**

Comment: yes it is working for me but under img tag my src attribute is looks like  this **src="@@PLUGINFILE@@/mc001-2.jpg"** so its make an empty box. so how could i change my src attribute like yours programmatically Thanks

Comment: You can set the src value on the img tag through Javascript code. You will need to run a JS snippet on your HTML page, and call that from your Activity's code, and pass it. Do you have an HTML page for this view?

Comment: No actually i parse the xml file using DOM parser and get content from <text> tag(which is actually html code ) and then load the content in WebView.

Comment: You will definitely need some JS manipulations to achieve that in this situation then.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution of my problem, I have replace my src attribute

```
src="@@PLUGINFILE@@/mc001-2.jpg" by this 

src='data:image/png;base64,<!- Base64 code for image -->'
```

and parsed it easily

and it worked for me Thanks for Replies.